# SSIS flat file destination generating more digits than in the database

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a simple SSIS package creating flat file from SQL view. The data in the view is two digits like 391.61 but when SSIS creates the flat file it is converted to 391.61000000000001. Is there something I missed?

Comment: Sounds more like you're using a `float` and you're seeing the *true* value of said `float`. This is expected behaviour. Most likely, you shouldn't be using a `float` in your database.

Comment: The view is showing that, what / how is the view getting the value?  Is it a calculated column?  Is it pulling straight from a table?  I would check both those data types.  If a formula, it is most likely casting differently so you are getting larger digits.

Comment: Yes you are right Thom A i am using float in the SQL table. now i altered to decimal  but the same result. what shall I do to fix?

Comment: If it's decimal with the right precision and scale end to end, that won't happen. Appears you're still using `float` *somewhere*.

Answer (score 0):

To correct this, you need to modify the mechanism for extracting data. Within your OLE/ADO/ODBC Source, change it from Table or View Name and write the equivalent query and explicitly shape your data as expected.

Before - Table or View Name

```
dbo.MyTable
```

After - Direct Query (name approximiate)

```
SELECT X.Col1, X.Col2, CAST(Col3 AS decimal(7,2)) AS Col3 FROM dbo.MyTable AS X;
```

Where Col3 is the column that needs coercion.

You can probably do this with a data conversion component or a derived column component but it's far cleaner just shaping the data before you bring it into the data flow.

The other thing to be aware of, SSIS may or may not "hear" the change in metadata - based on whether the new column width will fit into the old one. And I *think* a decimal can fit in a float. Switching from table or view name to a query probably is radical enough to reset the metadata, otherwise use a query like `SELECT 1 as FooBarBlee` and click OK. Observe all the downstream components show red Xs. Replace that query with the correct query and now your column names and metadata are corrected and you should be good.

If not, then you need to examine the definition of your Flat File Connection Manager. On the Columns tab, examine Col3 and see how that was defined and adjust it as needed.